# Use Windows built in MP3 decoder to play audio?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, audio, mp3

How do I from C or C++ use the MP3 decoder supposedly built in with Windows since Windows Media Player 6.1?

I want to play an mp3 file without having to depend on any other third party library such as for instance LAME.DLL.

<sup>*I updated the question to better fit the answers I got, since I liked them a lot. [Related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125234/how-to-access-raw-decoded-audio-data-using-windows-built-in-mp3-decoder)*</sup>

Comment: It's going to involve COM programming of DirectShow filters - building a filter graph. I don't have any code, so I don't have an answer. But hopefully you can have something to google for now: How to decode an mp3 with DirectShow?

Comment: That would have been a good answer in its own right.

Comment: Nah, unless an answer includes code (or pseudo-code), it's not an acceptable answer. i only know that you *can* construct a filter-graph with DirectShow COM objects to be able to access the data. i know that it is more complicated than "*just letting Windows play the MP3*", since you want the decoded waveform data. But it is possible (tools like VirtualDub and AviSynth do it).

Comment: http://code4k.blogspot.se/2010/05/playing-mp3-in-c-using-plain-windows.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control an audio channel (in order to make it play anything, including MP3) with mciSendString http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709492%28VS.85%29.aspx

Here's an example (it's in C#, but it's basically the same principle):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/152f0149-a62a-446d-a205-91256da7845d

Here is the same principle in C:

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/268167

Comment: And this seems to be it in C: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/code/268167

Comment: That looked really, really simple, so I am accepting your answer, specifically the last C link.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Ohh, i thought you wanted to *decode* an MP3, not simply play it!

Comment: @IanBoyd, I see how that happened. And I really want to eventually, can you do that in Windows with its built in mp3 decoder? That would be really fascinating.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant In Silco's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121570/use-windows-built-in-mp3-decoder/8121768#8121768) is the best head-start to that. In his case he calls the `RenderFile` method, which does everything required to **"play"** a file. You need to start with the same filter graph, but then access the raw (e.g. signed integer) data stream. i don't know *how* to do that in DirectShow. i know it's possible, but i don't know how. So i'll have to leave it to someone more knowledgeable to mention what's needed to access data moving between filter elements.

Comment: Thanks!  When (if) I get around to do that, I know what question to ask. Heck, I may just as well ask it now...

Comment: @IanBoyd, there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125234/how-to-access-raw-decoded-audio-data-using-windows-built-in-mp3-decoder

Answer (score 11):

Sure. Like lots of other things in the Windows API, there's more than one way to go about playing `.mp3` files. The "easiest" way to do this programmatically is using DirectShow. The MSDN docs even include a minimal code example on a page aptly called ["How To Play a File"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098.aspx) to get you started:

```
// Visual C++ example
#include <dshow.h>
#include <cstdio>
// For IID_IGraphBuilder, IID_IMediaControl, IID_IMediaEvent
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib") 

// Obviously change this to point to a valid mp3 file.
const wchar_t* filePath = L"C:/example.mp3"; 

int main()
{
    IGraphBuilder *pGraph = NULL;
    IMediaControl *pControl = NULL;
    IMediaEvent   *pEvent = NULL;

    // Initialize the COM library.
    HRESULT hr = ::CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::printf("ERROR - Could not initialize COM library");
        return 0;
    }

    // Create the filter graph manager and query for interfaces.
    hr = ::CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                        IID_IGraphBuilder, (void **)&pGraph);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        ::printf("ERROR - Could not create the Filter Graph Manager.");
        return 0;
    }

    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pControl);
    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent, (void **)&pEvent);

    // Build the graph.
    hr = pGraph->RenderFile(filePath, NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // Run the graph.
        hr = pControl->Run();
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            // Wait for completion.
            long evCode;
            pEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &evCode);

            // Note: Do not use INFINITE in a real application, because it
            // can block indefinitely.
        }
    }
    // Clean up in reverse order.
    pEvent->Release();
    pControl->Release();
    pGraph->Release();
    ::CoUninitialize();
}
```

Make sure you read through [the DirectShow documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454.aspx) to get an idea of what's supposed to happen in a proper DirectShow application.

---

To "feed" media data into a graph, you need to implement a `IAsyncReader`. Fortunately, [the Windows SDK includes a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317573.aspx) that implements an `IAsyncReader` called `CAsyncReader`. The sample reads a media file into a memory buffer then uses `CAsyncReader` to stream the data into the graph. This may be what you want. On my machine the sample is located in the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\multimedia\directshow\filters\async`.

Comment: Can you also play from a memory buffer instead of a file path?  If you don't know I'll just start reading filter graph docs. Thanks again!

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: Actually it means ["performed on computer or via computer simulation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_silico). :-)

Comment: Is it this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390089(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: The DirectShow API is quite comprehensive, so it's actually not as simple as just using `IGraphBuilder::Render()`. Let me see if there's a way to feed bytes from a memory buffer into a DirectShow graph.

Comment: And that code looks really proper and "programmatic", so I give it a +1

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant: To feed data into a graph from memory you need to implement an `IAsyncReader`. Fortunately, [the Windows SDK includes a sample that implements `IAsyncReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317573.aspx). You may want to start there.

Comment: Ok, very good. This looks like the more solid approach to me, but I am going to implement the MCI approach first because it looks so easy to do, but I really want avoid the file mess and go the memory buffer route eventually. Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892800/how-to-get-uncompressed-byte-array-from-directshow