# How to access raw decoded audio data using Windows' built in mp3 decoder?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, directshow

Since Windows Media Player 6.1, Windows has its' own mp3 decoder. Can I use that decoder to get access to the decoded audio (raw) data?

I assume it would have to be done with DirectShow.

<sup>[Related but not the same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121570/use-windows-built-in-mp3-decoder/8121768#8121768)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a [sample grabber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) into the graph after the mp3 decoder. The sample grabber allows you to configure a callback that gets called as each sample passes through the media pipeline.

Your graph would look something like

```
mp3 file -> mp3 decoder -> sample grabber -> renderer
```

Comment: Can I forego the renderer totally, or do I always need a renderer?

Comment: You can add in a null renderer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390934(v=vs.85).aspx). However I see that it has been deprecated (first time I'm seeing that). I'm guessing the deprecation has something to do with MS pushing WMF though I think it'll be a while until that takes over from DS completely.