# simple .wav or .mp3 playbck in Windows - where has it gone?

Tags: winapi, audio, mp3

Is there a "modern" replacement for the old Windows sndPlaySound() function, which was a very convenient way of playing a .wav file in the background while you focused on other matters?  I now find myself needing to play an .mp3 file in the background and am wondering how to accomplish the same thing in a relatively easy way that the system supports inherently.  Perhaps there's a COM component to acccomplish basic .mp3 playback?

Comment: [Couple of suggestions here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121570/use-windows-built-in-mp3-decoder-to-play-audio).

Answer (score 2):

Over years there have been a few audio and media related APIs and there are a few ways to achieve the goal.

The best in terms of absence of third party libs, best OS version coverage, feature set and simplicity is DirectShow API. 15 years old and still beats the hell out of rivals, supported in all versions of Windows that current and a few of previous versions of Visual Studio could target, except WinRT.

The code snippet below plays MP3 and WMA files. It is `C++` however since it is all COM it is well portable across languages.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <dshow.h>
#include <dshowasf.h>
#include <atlcom.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")

#define V(x) ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(x))

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    static LPCTSTR g_pszPath = _T("F:\\Music\\Cher - Walking In Memphis.mp3");
    V(CoInitialize(NULL));
    {
        CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> pGraphBuilder;
        V(pGraphBuilder.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph));
        CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pBaseFilter;
        V(pBaseFilter.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WMAsfReader));
        CComQIPtr<IFileSourceFilter> pFileSourceFilter = pBaseFilter;
        ATLASSERT(pFileSourceFilter);
        V(pFileSourceFilter->Load(CT2COLE(g_pszPath), NULL));
        V(pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pBaseFilter, NULL));
        CComPtr<IEnumPins> pEnumPins;
        V(pBaseFilter->EnumPins(&pEnumPins));
        CComPtr<IPin> pPin;
        ATLVERIFY(pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPin, NULL) == S_OK);
        V(pGraphBuilder->Render(pPin));
        CComQIPtr<IMediaControl> pMediaControl = pGraphBuilder;
        CComQIPtr<IMediaEvent> pMediaEvent = pGraphBuilder;
        ATLASSERT(pMediaControl && pMediaEvent);
        V(pMediaControl->Run());
        LONG nEventCode = 0;
        V(pMediaEvent->WaitForCompletion(INFINITE, &nEventCode));
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

If you are playing your own files you are sure to not contain large ID3 tag sections, [the code might be twice as short](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/Miscellaneous/PlayMp3File/PlayMp3File.cpp#L21).

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to a lot of problems like this is to simply call out to a command line program with system("play.exe soundfile.mp3") or equivalent. Just treat the command line as another API, an API that is has extensive functionality and is standard, portable, flexible, easy to debug and easy to modify. It may not be as efficient as calling a library function but that often doesn't matter, particularly if the program being called is already in the disk cache. Incidentally, avoid software complexity just because it's "modern"; often that's evidence of an architecture astronaut and poor programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Modern", do you mean a Windows 8 WinRT API?  Or do you mean, "an API slightly newer than the ones invented for Windows 3.1"?

A survey of audio and video apis can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

For classic Windows desktop applications, there's [PlaySound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can play any WAV file.

For MP3, my team invented a solution using DirectSound and the [Windows Media Format SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The latter can decode any WMA and MP3 file. We fed the audio stream directly into a DSound buffer. This is not for the faint of heart.

You could likely use the higher level alternative, the [Windows Media Player API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a very legacy alternative, but is easy to get something up and working.  [Media Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.asp) is the replacement for DirectShow.

Comment: PlaySound is an ancient but adequate solution, especially when the time to implement something more sophisticated can't be justified.  I was just hoping for something equivalent to the iOS AVAudioPlayer, where you can accomplish this with about five lines of code.  This is Win32 though.  Sigh ...